# How to set up permissions on external hard drive in order to use it to backup using rsync?

Tags: permissions, rsync, backup

So I have recently installed arch linux, and I was looking into a good way to back up my data. Looking at the wiki, I decided I followed this gude: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/full_system_backup_with_rsync.

My command is

`sudo rsync -aAXv --exclude={"/dev/*","/proc/*","/sys/*","/tmp/*","/run/*","/mnt/*","/media/*","/lost+found"} / /run/media/jakev/BACKUPDISK/2016.03.27/`

This is not working though. I get a bunch of errors like this

`rsync: chown "/run/media/jakev/BACKUPDISK/2016.03.27/usr/bin/.grops.IsCNPi" failed: Operation not permitted (1)`

If I keep letting it run, every single time it will get stuck on the file `usr/bin/msgfilter`

I think that it is something to do with the permissions on the drive? Change the owner? I am fairly new to arch linux, so please help me out.

Thank you all so much!

Edit: So I got this to run all of the way by not using sudo. Although, at the end, I get this error `rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1178) [sender=3.1.2]`

Comment: 1. You don't need `/*` on the end of each of those `rsync` excludes.

Comment: 2. What type of filesystem is in use on `/run/media/jakev/BACKUPDISK`?

Comment: @celada it is msdos. And I just had those there because that is what the guide recomended.

Comment: @celada see my edit.

Answer (score 3):

`rsync` is complaining about being unable to set the owner of a file on the backup disk because the filesystem type you are using on the backup disk has no concept of ownership of files.

It's not a fatal error, and `rsync` will succeed anyway, but if you want your backup to be faithful to the contents of the original filesystem and as useful as possible in the event that it needs to be restored, it would be best for you to back up to an external disk with a filesystem that supports enough POSIX features to support a POSIX system. Ownership is probably not the only thing `rsync` is failing to back up: you're probably missing some permissions, extended attributes (relevant because you specified `-X`), symlinks, hard links (not relevant because you did not specify `-H` but I recommend that you do), and file timestamps as well.

Comment: Thank you! Do you have a recomended filesystem?

Comment: Sure, `ext4` is the most popular filesystem for Linux. If in doubt, use that.